# 120 V on 2 light sockets, and 15 V on a third

Tags: electrical, lighting

I just bought a new ceiling light that has 3 heads (3 light sockets). One of the lights doesn't work. When I use my multimeter, I read 120 V on 2 of the sockets, and about 15 to 20 V on the third one (the one that doesn't work).

Is this a bad socket? What could be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: A picture showing how the wires are connected would help, but do think it is a defective light fixture and you should return it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible there is a bad connection in the fixture. If 3 wires come out to the connection point you may have one that is not fully connected.

If like many fixtures that only 1 white and 1 black come out it’s time to return it and get a new one because they have a bad splice or lamp socket.